# Make multiple forms submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, email

I have a form on a site which should perform four actions when the button has been pressed. It should send the form action on four email marketing services. (aweber, mailchimp, GetResponse, and GoToWebinar)

Is it possible to set multiple actions from a submit button on a one form?  How can I do so?

Comment: Yes, just send multiple ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
 <form action="handle_user.php" method="POST />
      <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit for Approval" name="approve">
    </form>
```

Your **PHP** file will be

```
if($_POST["save"]) {
  //User hit the save button, handle accordingly
}
//You can do an else, but I prefer a separate statement
if($_POST["approve"]) {
  //User hit the Submit for Approval button, handle accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when a form is submitted, it will load a web page with the form data sent to it.  However, if you want to make multiple submissions, there are a few things you could do.  You could make it so that the form could submit to your site which makes the submissions to the other sites, or you could make some ajax calls to the other sites from your form's onsubmit event.